# Double Stack-last elements

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a homework about making a Double stack, consisting of `redStack` and `blueStack`, and have their own operations (e.g `redPush`, `bluePush`). But for the `pop`, it knows the last added element in both stacks, and remove it. My question is how could I make it know the last added elements?

Here's my code:

```
public T pop() {
  if (redCounter > blueCounter) {
    redCounter--;
    return redStack.pop();
  }
  if (blueCounter > redCounter) {
    blueCounter--;
    return blueStack.pop();
  } 
}
```

My code here shows removing the last element depending on the counter for each stack. But how can I know the last added one if they are equal to each other? Thanks.

Comment: Often stacks have a `peek` method that allows you to look at the top of the stack without removing it. So `if (redStack.peek().equals(blueStack.peek())` could do it.

Comment: Are you saying when `pop` is called, you pop the most recent element, red or blue? So if somebody pushed blue, blue, red, blue, then the next time to `pop` you'd return blue?

Comment: @JimMischel yeah right, but in your situation according to my code, it will return blue. but if it pushed blue,red,blue,red, then i want it to pop red.

Comment: I don't see why you can't just use a single stack for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must use two stacks for this then I would maintain a third stack `lastAdded` that pushes a label for the last pushed element. If the last pushed element was red, then push `0`, otherwise `1`.

Then in pop you check `lastAdded` for last type of element pushed, and pop from the corresponding stack.

```
public T pop() {
  if (lastAdded.empty()) {
    throw Exception();
  }
  int lastColor = lastAdded.pop();
  if (lastColor == 0) {
    return redStack.pop();
  }
  return blueStack.pop();
}
```

Besides this I would simply use a single stack for all operations, since per your description of the problem the operations you want seem no different then that of a single stack.

---

Update: With exactly two stacks you would have to make some modifications to the stack itself. Instead of pushing the value itself, push the value + a counter. When popping, pop the element off the stack that has a greater counter value:

```
class DoubleStack {
  // Java 7 has its own pair class
  private class Pair<T, U> {
    private T first;
    private U second;
    public Pair(T x, U y) { first = x; second = y; }
    public T getKey() { return first; }
    public U getValue() { return second; }
  }

  private Stack<Pair<Integer, Integer>> redStack = new Stack<>(), blueStack = new Stack<>();
  private int c = 0;

  public boolean empty() {
      return redStack.empty() && blueStack.empty();
  }

  public void pushRed(int x) {
      redStack.push(new Pair<>(x, c++));
  }

  public void pushBlue(int x) {
    blueStack.push(new Pair<>(x, c++));
  }

  public int pop() {
    if (empty()) {
      return Integer.MAX_VALUE; // throw an exception
    } 
    if (redStack.empty()) {
      return popBlue();
    }
    if (blueStack.empty()) {
      return popRed();
    }
    if (redStack.peek().getValue() > blueStack.peek().getValue()) {
      return popRed();
    }
    return popBlue();
  }

  private int popRed() {
    return redStack.pop().getKey();
  }

  private int popBlue() {
    return blueStack.pop().getKey();
  }
};
```

Comment: The third stack is what I was going to recommend. No telling why two stacks are required.

Comment: actually it is a homework, and I tried using a third stack, but the instructor said use only two stacks. That is why I am struggling, especially where there is another method to display the element of the two stack, in the same order were they added. Thanks anyway ☺.